# Script to Capture VHS Tapes Using the Hauppauge 610 USB-Live 2 Analog Video Digitizer and Video Capture Device

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This device is supported in the Linux kernel for modern Linux distributions. I have had the most success using VLC Media Player in digitizing (compared to FFmpeg which has rendered a pixelated picture). However, how could I create a script to make digitizing VHS's as efficient as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script has been efficient for me for digitizing home VHS's. You'll need VLC Media Player and FFmpeg if you want to convert to mp4 for ideal compression level. Adjust `v4l2:///dev/video0 :input-slave=alsa://hw:2,0` (video and audio input) if needed according to your machine. You can find this information by using VLC and going to Media > Capture Device. There you can see the Video device name and Audio device name.

It is an mpeg2 device. Using VLC to encode directly to mp4 or h264 will produce video with lips out of sync. This is why I first encode to mpeg2 and then process to mp4. FFmpeg here is set to use 3 of 4 CPU cores so it does not max out the CPU. You'll want to adjust `-threads 3` according to your CPU. If you're not sure, `-threads 3` can be removed. Be sure to mark the script as executable before using: `chmod +x your-script-name`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Enter the name of the file.
read -p "Enter file name: " filename

# Enter how many minutes.
read -p "How many minutes? (If left blank by hitting enter, the default is 124 minutes.): " minutes
if [ -z "$minutes" ]; then
    minutes=124
fi

# Remove any spaces in the file name.
filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/ /-/g')

# This is for metadata. It will show up in the media player playlist or after clicking Properties (in OS X Info) on the file context menu.
read -p "Enter a description: " details

# Turn off sleep. You can uncomment this only if using Xfce.
# xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-ac -s 14

# Create Videos directory if not there.
if ! [ -d $HOME/Videos ]; then mkdir $HOME/Videos; fi

# Encode video. 
timeout --foreground ${minutes}m cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :input-slave=alsa://hw:2,0 :v4l2-standard=NTSC :live-caching=300 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=48000,fps=29.97,deinterlace}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=ts,dst='$HOME/Videos/$filename.ts'}'

# Convert to libx264 to compress further, add in the metadata comments, and keep CPU usage to 75%. 
ffmpeg -i $HOME/Videos/$filename.ts -s 720x480 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 22 -acodec copy -metadata comment="$details" -threads 3 $HOME/Videos/$filename.mp4
```

Comment: Why not just use `ffmpeg`? I don't really see the reason to use `cvlc`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I agree that it would be better to use only `ffmpeg` instead of `cvlc` as well. However, I have tried a number of configurations with `ffmpeg`. They all render a very pixelated/low quality picture.

Comment: Try replacing `cvlc` with something like: `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i hw:2,0 -vf format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 22 -c:a aac -metadata comment="$details" output.mp4` If that works then you can add more filters (but make sure it doesn't slow down encoding below realtime, or else use a faster preset): `-vf yadif=1,hqdn3d,format=yuv420p`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard It needs to be `mpeg2` instead. I tried going directly to `libx264` in the past. The lips sync is off. The device is designed for `mpeg2`.

Comment: Did you try the command?  Your comment "the device is designed for `mpeg2`" doesn't make sense to me. The input format does not really matter: `ffmpeg` will completely decode whatever format the device provides to raw video. If it is out of sync it is not because you are **not** re-encoding to MPEG-2 video.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Actually your command above did not have picture issues. However, now the audio is skipping out every other second.

Comment: For audio issues, I found that ffmpeg needs an extra parameter for the audio capture to correct the lipsync issue. Some solutions use a `-q:a` or `-qscale:a` for the audio, but I didn't have success until I used a bitrate `-b:a` parameter. The parameter `-b:a 256k` worked for me. So, `... -c:a aac -b:a 256k ...` and no more lipsync issues.